# Rails 7 - Active Storage and Filepond

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7, filepond

So I have a form page for `Orders`, and I implemented Files Upload using `Active Storage`, and also Implemented Drag and Drop feature called `Filepond` using `importmap` and `javascript`

However when I start my rails server using `rails s` and navigate to the form page, `Filepond` does not appear (Drag n Drop feature)[image]

---

NOW when I refresh the page, then it loads up the `Filepond`
[image: Filepond]

NOW again when I navigate to some other page and come back to the form, the filepond does not load
[image]

[image]

> app/javascript/application.js

```
// Configure your import map in config/importmap.rb. Read more: https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import "controllers"
import "bootstrap"
import "custom/custom"
import "filepond"
import "filepond-plugin-image-preview"
```

> app/javascript/custom/custom.js

```
// Import FilePond
import * as FilePond from 'filepond';

// Import the plugin code
import FilePondPluginImagePreview from 'filepond-plugin-image-preview';

// Register the plugin
FilePond.registerPlugin(FilePondPluginImagePreview);

// Get a reference to the file input element
const inputElement = document.querySelector('#files-upload');

// Create a FilePond instance
const pond = FilePond.create(inputElement, {
    credits: {},
    storeAsFile: true,
    allowMultiple: true,
    allowReorder: true,
});
```

> views/orders/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_with(model: order) do |f| %>
 .......
 .......
 <%= f.file_field :files, multiple: true, direct_upload: true, 
 required: true, id:"files-upload" %>
 ........
 ........
<% end %>
```

**CONCLUSION:**

Every time I navigate to the form page, I will have to refresh the page once in order for the `filepond's drag n drop feature` to work

so is there any way to fix this in rails 7 so that we never need to refresh the page for `filepond` to work??

Comment: Please include the code you're working with. Debugging a screenshot is impossible

Comment: sorry for the mistake, I uploaded it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I got to know the problem, the problem lies with JavaScript, Since Rails 7 uses Turbo to handle JavaScript, we need to use Event `"turbo:load"` provided by Turbo Hotwire,

- `turbo:load` fires once after the initial page load, and again after every Turbo visit. Access visit timing metrics with the event.detail.timing object.

source: https://turbo.hotwired.dev/reference/events

> custom.js

```
// Import FilePond
import * as FilePond from 'filepond';

// Import the plugin code
import FilePondPluginImagePreview from 'filepond-plugin-image-preview';

// Register the plugin
FilePond.registerPlugin(FilePondPluginImagePreview);


document.addEventListener("turbo:load", loadFilePond);

function loadFilePond(){
    // Get a reference to the file input element
    const inputElement = document.querySelector('#files-upload');

    // Create a FilePond instance
    const pond = FilePond.create(inputElement, {
        credits: {},
        storeAsFile: true,
        allowMultiple: true,
        allowReorder: true,
    });
}
```